# How to query timestamp of type int64?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some data on BigQuery containing a timestamp field which is displayed in the format `2017-11-13T02:40:57.948000`.

Using the following

```
WHERE
 timestamp > '2018-1-1T-00:00:00.00000'
```

returns the error `Argument type mismatch in function GREATER: 'timestamp' is type int64, '2018-1-1T-00:00:00.00000' is type string`

And when I tried using a unix value such as

```
WHERE
 timestamp > 1517443200
```

it works but does not give the desired output - it returns everything in the data frame. What is the correct way to query this field for a certain date range?

Comment: Afaik Bigquery uses a variation of Standard SQL timestamp literals: `TIMESTAMP("2018-01-01 00:00:00")`

Comment: @dnoeth so how would one query this? Something like `WHERE
timestamp > TIMESTAMP("2018-01-01 00:00:00")`? (very new to sql)

Comment: Are you using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sqld)? It should "just work", assuming that your timestamp string is valid and `timestamp` is actually a `TIMESTAMP` value.

Comment: (But if you don't actually have a `TIMESTAMP`, you need to use e.g. `TIMESTAMP_MICROS` to convert the `INT64`).

Comment: I managed to figure it out. Using `CAST(x AS DATETIME)` on the argument returns the correct result :) . Thanks for your input